# ArcGIS tells me 'raster' isn't defined

Tags: arcpy, zonal-statistics, nameerror

I am trying to get zonal statistics for a set of geographical units for several years and I would like to get the output in one dbf table, where the rows mark the geographical units and each column is the mean for a different year. The input for each year is in a different raster.

When I am running the code below, I get "NameError: name 'raster' is not defined". I don't understand why raster is not defined?

```
import arcpy, os


destination_path=r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff'
shapefile=r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff\tribe_country_split_merge_join.shp'

arcpy.env.workspace=r'\\Mac\Home\Desktop\arc_stuff'

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("lights_*.tif")

final_dbf = os.path.join(destination_path, raster + "database.dbf")
firstDone = False;

for raster in rasters:
  destination_raster = os.path.join(destination_path, raster + ".dbf")
  print destination_raster
  print raster
  arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(shapefile, "FID", raster,destination_raster,"DATA","MEAN")

  if not firstDone:
    firstDone = True;
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(shapefile, "FID", raster,final_dbf,"DATA","MEAN")

  else:
  arcpy.JoinField_management(final_dbf, "FID", destination_raster, "FID", ["MEAN"])
```

Error message in full:
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 8, in 
NameError: name 'raster' is not defined

Comment: Please post only the [code necessary to generate the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (in this case, through line 8), which likely would have helped you identify the problem on your own.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
final_dbf = os.path.join(destination_path, raster + "database.dbf")
```

The program does not know that `raster` is one of the rasters from rasters list named `rasters` yet. I am not an expert but I guess the solution would be to define `final_dbf` in each iteration within `for raster in rasters` loop.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the issue @Alešinar identifies if you look at the help file on ListRasters() you are not following the syntax of this function.

This line:

```
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("lights_*.tif")
```

should be:

```
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("lights_*","TIF")
```